# Print box bigger than the printer bed

Tags: fusion360

I am trying to make a box that is 420 mm wide by 86 mm tall by 100 mm long, I wonder if there is a good technique to design, cut, print and fit all parts together to be safe and hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making a simple box? Or does it have some kind of detail or structure? The photo below exemplifies a structure attached to connectors that have been created outside of Fusion, but you can also use it as an idea to create your own!

[image]

[Link to OPENSCAD LIBRARY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d8vv.jpg)

If you are thinking of cutting into parts, you can also create a kind of male / female (puzzle) in the parts that fit. Something like that ...

[image]

Here is some interesting information to study [How to design Snap-fit Joints for 3D Printing](https://www.3dhubs.com/knowledge-base/how-design-snap-fit-joints-3d-printing)

Comment: Great this is what I needed... :)